# disallow anonymous bind in openldap

Tags: ldap, openldap

Folks,

I have followed the instructions here http://tuxnetworks.blogspot.com/2010/06/howto-ldap-server-on-1004-lucid-lynx.html to setup my OpenLdap and its working just fine, except an anonymous user can bind to my server and see the whole user/group structure. LDAP is running over SSL.

I have read online that i can add `disallow bind_anon and require authc` in the slapd.conf file and it will be disabled but there is no slapd.conf file to begin with and since this doesn't use slapd.conf for its configuration as i understand OpenLdap has moved to a cn=config setup so it wont read that file even if i create one. i have looked online without any luck.

I believe i need to change something in here

```
olcAccess: to attrs=userPassword by dn="cn=admin,dc=tuxnetworks,dc=com" write by anonymous auth by self write by * none
olcAccess: to attrs=shadowLastChange by self write by * read
olcAccess: to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: to * by dn="cn=admin,dc=tuxnetworks,dc=com" write by * read
```

but i am not sure what. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

-shashank

Answer (score 0):

> olcAccess: to * by
>   dn="cn=admin,dc=tuxnetworks,dc=com"
>   write by * read

This rule of yours makes the default to allow read access to everybody. Try changing the final 'read' to 'none', but better still have a look at how this syntax works and devise your own rule.

Answer (score 0):

```
olcAccess: to * by self write by anonymous auth by * none
```

This directive allows the user to modify their entry, allows anonymous to authenticate against these entries, and allows all others to read these entries.